# Preferred MongoDb Schema Design

Tags: mongodb, schema, database-schema

I am working on a MongoDb based application whose current schema is like below :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5cc69f8c5344dfe60cb30645"),
"Content":""
"Location":""
"topic1_device" : "device1,device2",
"topic1_category" : "category1,category2",
"topic1_mentions" : "",
"topic1_phrase" : "",
"topic1_sentence" : "",
"topic2_mentions" : "",
"topic2_category" : "",
"topic2_device" : "",
"topic2_mentions" : "",
"topic2_phrase" : "",
"topic2_regex" : "",
....
10 similar topics
```

As you can see topic_device can have multiple device and i have their corresponding categories in topic1_category.
  Most of my queries are aggregation  and get queries. Like getting pair count of all topic 1 device and category.

Currently my schema is flat and i want to change it to either of the below schema :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5cc69f8c5344dfe60cb30645"),
"Content":""
"Location":""
"topic1":{

"category" : {"device1":"category1",{   device2:"category2"}
"mentions" : "",
"phrase" : "",
"sentence" : "",
"mentions" : "",
"category" : "",
```

or

```
"topic": [
{
  "device": "device1",
  "mention": "correct",
  "phrase": "",
  "sentence": "",
},
{
  "device": "device2",
  "mention": "wrong",
  "fhe_category": "catgeory2",
  "phrase": "",
  "sentence": "
```

]